# How do I combine to classes but send second class to partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a class which consists of agents of properties each agent has mutiple properties against them so in my view model i have the following. My question is If I just reference Agents in the view on my view of Agent.cshtml listed below

```
public class Agents
{
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public int RatingsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public string Bookerish { get; set; }
    public string Specialties { get; set; }
    public int LicenseNo { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public double LocalKnowledge { get; set; }
    public double ProcessExpertise { get; set; }
    public double Responsiveness { get; set; }
    public double NegotiationSkills { get; set; }
    public int Reviews { get; set; }
    public double RatingAverage { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Property Class

```
public class Property 
{
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string reprsented { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Beds { get; set; }
    public double Baths { get; set; }

    public double SQFT { get; set; }

    public Boolean isFeatuered { get; set; }

    public int isActiveListing { get; set; }
    public Boolean isPastSale { get; set; }
}
```

model Agents

```
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "About";
 }


 @Html.Partial("ActiveListings.cshtml")

 <div class="l-divider l-divider--big"></div>
```

Where I am here how would one access the properties to send to the model that it would render a list of properties for that agent that has been stored.

I need someway to add to this pass  the model property of agents here.

@Html.Partial("ActiveListings.cshtml")

In My agent controller i have the following index method where would I need to add my properies to here.

```
 Agents _newAgent = new Agents();

        _newAgent.AgentId = 5;
        _newAgent.Name = "Melissa Crosby";
        _newAgent.Specialties = "Property Management, Buyer’s Agent, Listing Agent";
        _newAgent.Bookerish = " Berkshire Hathaway HomeServices Elite Real Estate";
        _newAgent.image = "uploads/agents/5.png";
        _newAgent.Reviews = 16;
        _newAgent.RatingAverage = 4.5;
        _newAgent.LocalKnowledge = 4.5;
        _newAgent.ProcessExpertise = 4.2;
        _newAgent.NegotiationSkills = 4.1;
        _newAgent.About = "<p> Being a full-service Realtor since 2007, I have been baptized by fire in a very tough housing market. I have successfully closed over 60 transactions and processed over 70 short sales both as the listing agent and some for other agents. I am very knowledgeable about lenders and their processes. I strive to exceed expectations and never forget that I am always accountable to my clients. </p> <p> My objective is to establish relationships for life, not just for the current transaction. I enjoy assisting home buyers and sellers to get moved to a better place, one that is exciting. </p>";
        _newAgent.LicenseNo = 5452129;
        return View(_newAgent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load the `Properties` collection of your `Agent` object and in your main view, you can pass the Properties collection as the model for the partial view.

```
Agents agent= new Agents();
agent.AgentId = 5;
agent.Name = "Melissa Crosby";
// To do : Fill other properties needed

// Load the Properties collection property
agent.Properties = new List<Property>{
  new Property { PropertyId=1, Details="4 Bedroom house"},
  new Property { PropertyId=2, Details="3 Bedroom house"},
};
return View(agent);
```

And in your main view

```
@model Agents
<h1>@Model.Name</h1>        
@Html.Partial("ActiveListings",Model.Properties)
```

Where your `ActiveListings` partial view is strongly typed to a collection of Property objects

```
@model List<Property>
@if (Model != null && Model.Any())
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <p>@item.Details</p>
        <p>@item.PropertyId</p>
    }
}

else
{
    <p>No properties found!</p>
}
```

Comment: How would one reference that at the top of the partial view btw here we have  @model Agents how would I tell the view I want to use properties

Comment: See the updated answer. The partial view will be strongly typed to a list of Property class.

Comment: But if its Agents.Property will this still pull the data saved in agent ?

Comment: As long as you set the `Properties` collection to a valid list of properties (As i shown in the answer) in your GET action method , It will be fine. In the answer i hard coded 2 properties, but you should write code to get the real data (may be from a table)

Comment: why when i try this is it saying that i must have a closing } even though I do in my partial view strange

Comment: That means you forgot to close the `}` somewhere in the view. There is noway i can tell you where it is. You have to check your code. One thing i usually do is, Remove a major part of the view code and simply put little code and see whether it works, If it works, slowly add little by little and you will find out where exactly it is missing it.

Comment: This line is braking it some reason mate       <img src="/images/property/home1.jpg" alt=""> is there something about image paths that would ?

Comment: Is image a self closing tag ? `<img src="someUrl" />`

Comment: yes it is i read someowhere a for each is not the best way to handle this